# how to append a string to a file that has been selected with JFileChooser in java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am writing a program that has multiple users, and I want each user to be able to save a file with a filename they choose, but, also append their username or a related key to the file name to help with searching later on. How can I adjust this code to do so?

For example, the user "bob" wants to save a file as "aFile.html". The file I want to actually save would be "aFile_bob.html"

```
    String user = "bob";
    // select a file to save output
    JFileChooser JfileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(defaultDirectory));
    JfileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("TestFile.html"));
    int i = JfileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (i != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
    File saveFile = JfileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    // somehow append "user" to saveFile name here?

    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `renameTo` method, like this:

```
int lastDot = saveFile.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
String name = saveFile.getName();
String ext = ""; // Might not have a file extension
if(lastDot > 0) { // At least one dot
    // Take substring of the last occurrence
    ext = saveFile.getName().substring(lastDot);
    name = name.substring(0, lastDot);
}

saveFile.renameTo(new File(defaultDirectory + "/" + name + "_" + user + ext));
```

Using this method, you don't need the FileOutputStream.

Comment: You might want to check if the file name contains more than one dot or no dots at all, otherwise your application could crash or rename the file wrongly. I have updated my answer to reflect this.